# Question regarding the degeneracy of vacuum state in various spacetimes

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, spacetime, quantum-gravity, vacuum

In a talk, it was mentioned that if one attempts to do quantum gravity in the following spacetimes (of any dimension), then the vacuum state has the following degeneracy.

1. In $AdS$ - There is a unique state satisfying $H |\psi\rangle = 0$, i.e. there is a unique vacuum state.
2. In Minkowski - There are certain number of states but not all in the Hilbert space which satisfy $H |\psi\rangle = 0$, i.e. the vacuum state is degenerate.
3. In $dS$ - All in the Hilbert space satisfy $H |\psi\rangle = 0$, i.e. the vacuum has infinite degeneracy.

I am not sure if the above claims (especially the last one) are correct. How does one prove these? If one looks from the viewpoint of canonical quantization of gravity, then the imposition of Hamiltonian constraint on the state space should give us $H |\psi\rangle = 0$ for all states. How do we resolve this? Is the problem related to notions of asymptotic symmetry?